# How to replace a words near the specific word in a text file using python

Tags: python-2.7

This is my example code to find a specific word "dut_decoded" in all lines in a text file and replace line by line with reference with another text file(Having New names in line by line)
  import re
    new_words = []

```
rep_file = open('Rename_Changes_Details.txt','r')

for line in rep_file:
    line = line.strip()
    new_words.append(line)

infile = open('Filter_Lines.txt','r')

i = 0
out = open('ip_list.txt','w')

for inlines in infile:
    inlines = re.sub('dut_decoded',new_words[i],inlines)
    out.write(inlines)
    i += 1
out.close()
infile.close()
```

But,i need to replace a words near the word of "out=" in all lines by the new names.
for example i have a text file with these lines

1.--bass_cut_off=45--out=sys_alg_oar_bass_extraction_BE45_SR32k0_IN8B0O_SP8F0H.wav

2.--bass_cut_off=0 --out=sys_alg_oar_all_beds_IN10B0O_SP10F2H.wav

3.--bass_cut_off=8--out=sys_alg_oar_bass_extraction_BE80_SR44k1_IN8B0O_SP8F0H.wav

Here i need to replace a word(sys_alg_oar_bass_extraction_BE45_SR32k0_IN8B0O_SP8F0H.wav) near to "out=" in first line.Like this process need to replace in all lines.New names is getting from "infile" in my code.
This "infile" having these below lines.

1. 100
2. 101
3. 103

like this.Finally i want these output like this.

1.--bass_cut_off=45--out=100

2.--bass_cut_off=0 --out=101

3.--bass_cut_off=8--out=102

Can you please guide me for this.

Comment: So what precisely is the problem with your current code?

Comment: This only replace a specific word in to a new name.but here i want rename different words to new name near by a word "out="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression library has a function to substitute parts of a match [re.sub( pattern, repl, string )](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

Use lookaheads `(?=...)` and lookbehinds (?<=...)

```
re.sub( "(?<=--out=)(.+)(?=\s)", "something", "--bass_cut_off=0 --out=sys_alg_oar_all_beds_IN10B0O_SP10F2H.wav" )
```

resulting in

```
'--bass_cut_off=0 --out=something'
```

In this example I could use also a negative lookahead `(?!...)`. Similarly you could use pattern `"(?<=--out=)(\w+)"`, and it would match until end of word, thus leaving `".wav"` suffix

```
'--bass_cut_off=0 --out=something.wav'
```

in this example equivalent to `"(?<=--out=)(.+)(?=.wav)"`

Comment: Fine.Here what is the function of "\w"

Comment: In short: any letter, number or an underscore. Longer description in https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Is this can include a characters after "."

Comment: `.` means any character. I'll change the example to `"(?<=--out=)(\w+)"` to be more clear. So this means: "--out= followed by a word", and since word is in `()`, let this word be a group which is substituted with "something"

Comment: sorry, my bad, I should've used `"\s"` instead

Comment: Ok .Thank you.Its fine